# Identify this baseplate

Tags: piece-information, part-identification, clone-brands

I recently purchased a large lot of LEGO parts. Most everything I'm familiar with, but there are a few pieces that I'd love to get some insight on if anyone here can help.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is a Megabloks baseplate, not LEGO.

For future reference - LEGO pieces will have "LEGO" stamped on the studs (where possible) and will have "(c) LEGO" somewhere on the inside in most cases as well. Difficult to read or find, but it is there upon close inspection. Your piece does not have any markings on the studs.

Comment: thanks yeah i noticed that these were lacking the lego stamp but didn't put 2 & 2 together. thanks!